# CakeDC/Users new role

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-3.0

I'm using the CakeDC/Users plugin and want add other user roles.

Right now I have the both superuser and user roles.

I'm doing the permissions control in the permissions.php.

I'm also overwriting the layout files. Tried initially force the role field in the form, but the plugin write the user role in the controllers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As steinkel posted in this issue: https://github.com/CakeDC/users/issues/513

You must add this line after the pathEntity in /vendor/cakedc/user/src/Controller/Traits/SimpleCrudTrait.php

```
$entity->role = $this->request->data('role');
```

Then **configure your form to pass the role field**. In my case, I passed this information with a select box.